# Spring File Upload Fails by 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

File upload API fails from angularjs post call. Followings is the file upload API code, 
FileUploadController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/v1")
public class FileUploadController {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext context;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/fileUpload", headers = "content-type=multipart/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<FileInfo> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile inputFile){
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        if(!inputFile.isEmpty()){
            try {
                String originalFileName = inputFile.getOriginalFilename();
                File destinationFile = new File(context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/images") + File.separator + originalFileName);
                inputFile.transferTo(destinationFile);
                fileInfo.setFileName(destinationFile.getPath());
                fileInfo.setFileSize(inputFile.getSize());
                headers.add("FileUploaded Successfully - ", originalFileName);

                return new ResponseEntity<FileInfo>(fileInfo, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new ResponseEntity<FileInfo>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<FileInfo>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

SimpleCorsFilter.java

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","false");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found] with root cause
```

Angularjs test code:

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);
        var uploadUrl = "http://xxx/v1/fileUpload";
        //var uploadUrl = "http://localhost:8080/xxx/v1/fileUpload";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };

}]);
```

Issue:
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Please help me to rectify this issue

Comment: Which version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: Angular 1.1.1 I am using.

Comment: Could you post your entire `SimpleCorsFilter.java` code . i think you spring application fails to scan your filter

Comment: Also remove this line `headers = "content-type=multipart/*"` from your backend controller . since from angular side you are sending `content-type=undefined`

Comment: @Ajit Soman. Check i just added my full cors filter code above.

Comment: where is @Component on top of cors filter? Have you created the bean else where ?

Comment: No, I haven't created bean definition for my cors filter. I will try to add @Component.

Comment: Please add @component annotation on your filter with out this your filter will get not registered with spring container

Comment: Added @Component annotation on cors filter class but it still throws the same issue.

Comment: Please provide entire code or provide us a github link to debug your code. So that i can provide you a better answer for your problem

Answer (score 2):

Make use of  `@CrossOrigin` on the controller method

see an example : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileUpload", headers = "content-type=multipart/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<FileInfo> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile inputFile){
```

Answer (score 0):

add whatever headers coming from request in response along with adding headers for Access-Control

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 issues, one is related to CORS and other answers tell you different alternatives (also, if you are trying from localhost domain there are other constraints that will prevent you * to work).

the other issue is the one triggering 500 http response status, which for sure is not related to CORS (you have a stacktrace to check, you didn't paste all in your question so cannot help you on that). Missing CORS headers will only trigger browser not allowing to do the ajax call (after an OPTIONS request to validate), but never an error on serverside.